# Is it possible to make a user-specific gallery?

Tags: gallery

I want to make a website where everyone makes their own private/public galleries so that when they log into the website with their own account, they can find their listed galleries.
If you have a plugin or a theme solution, please link that theme/plugin in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by adding custom fields to user profile pages, I would use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) and make a repeater field that shows on profile pages.

Also, [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gallery-for-users/) or [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-upg/) seem to do what your looking for.